# alpha and beta estimates for beta binomial and beta distributions

Tags: python, r, scipy, beta, parameterization

I am trying to fit my data to a beta-binomial distribution and estimate the alpha and beta shape parameters. For this distribution, the prior is taken from a beta distribution. Python does not have a fit function for beta-binomial but it does for beta. The python beta fitting and R beta binomial fitting is close but systematically off.

R:

```
library("VGAM")
x = c(222,909,918,814,970,346,746,419,610,737,201,865,573,188,450,229,629,708,250,508)
y = c(2,18,45,11,41,38,22,7,40,24,34,21,49,35,31,44,20,28,39,17)
fit=vglm(cbind(y, x) ~ 1, betabinomialff, trace = TRUE)
Coef(fit)
   shape1    shape2 
  1.736093 26.870768
```

python:

```
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np
x = np.array([222,909,918,814,970,346,746,419,610,737,201,865,573,188,450,229,629,708,250,508], dtype=float)
y = np.array([2,18,45,11,41,38,22,7,40,24,34,21,49,35,31,44,20,28,39,17])
scipy.stats.beta.fit((y)/(x+y), floc=0, fscale=1)
    (1.5806623978910086, 24.031893492546242, 0, 1)
```

I have done this many times and it seems like python is systematically a little bit lower than the R results. I was wondering if this is an input error on my part or just a difference in the way they are calculated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that fitting a beta-binomial model is just not the same as fitting a Beta model with the values equal to the ratios.  I'm going to illustrate here with the `bbmle` package, which will fit similar models to `VGAM` (but with which I'm more familiar).

Preliminaries:

```
library("VGAM")  ## for dbetabinom.ab
x <- c(222,909,918,814,970,346,746,419,610,737,
       201,865,573,188,450,229,629,708,250,508)
y <- c(2,18,45,11,41,38,22,7,40,24,34,21,49,35,31,44,20,28,39,17)

library("bbmle")
```

Fit beta-binomial model:

```
mle2(y~dbetabinom.ab(size=x+y,shape1,shape2),
     data=data.frame(x,y),
     start=list(shape1=2,shape2=30))
## Coefficients:
##    shape1    shape2 
##  1.736046 26.871526
```

This agrees more or less perfectly with the `VGAM` result you quote.

Now use the same framework to fit a Beta model instead:

```
mle2(y/(x+y) ~ dbeta(shape1,shape2),
     data=data.frame(x,y),
     start=list(shape1=2,shape2=30))
## Coefficients:
##    shape1    shape2 
## 1.582021 24.060570
```

This fits your Python, beta-fit result.  (I'm sure if you used `VGAM` to fit the Beta you'd get the same answer too.)

Comment: In case anyone is uncertain who wrote the `bbmle` package (and why Ben is more familiar with it), they have only to type `maintainer('bbmle')` in an R console session.

Comment: Then, I think I know what 'bb' stands for in `bbmle`!

Comment: I probably would have named it differently if I'd known it was going to be useful/popular in the long run ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `conjugate_prior` package for `python`

See code for a coin-flip example:

```
from conjugate_prior import BetaBinomial
heads = 95
tails = 105
prior_model = BetaBinomial() #Uninformative prior
updated_model = prior_model.update(heads, tails)
credible_interval = updated_model.posterior(0.45, 0.55)
print ("There's {p:.2f}% chance that the coin is fair".format(p=credible_interval*100))
predictive = updated_model.predict(50, 50)
print ("The chance of flipping 50 Heads and 50 Tails in 100 trials is {p:.2f}%".format(p=predictive*100))
```

Code taken from [here](https://github.com/urigoren/conjugate_prior)